Orion Map [reflect status nodes in rectangle]
Good morning.
We no longer have the network atlas and are only using Orion Map.
We have a rectangle with 6 nodes inside that rectangle.
We want the rectangle to reflect the same color that one of the nodes displays after a status change.
How can I do this on Orion Map, without Network Altas?
NOTE: We created a group containing these 6 nodes.
Thanks!
Response about correct action to create this reflect with Orion Map
